# UPDATE FUNCTION based on matching other column using SQL query in Access 2010

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table '1042sRegistration' I'm trying to update.  It has a column 'IssueNumber' that I need to populate with values.  Another table '1042sTransactions' has an 'IssueNumber' column as well that I want to pull the values from.  These two tables also both have a column 'AccountNumber' that I'm trying to use as the condition to fill in 'IssueNumber' values.  When I run the following query:

```
UPDATE 1042sRegistration
    SET [1042sRegistration].IssueNumber = [1042sTransactions].IssueNumber
    WHERE [1042sRegistration].AccountNumber = [1042sTransactions].AccountNumber;
```

0 rows are updated - even though I know they have thousands of matching 'AccountNumbers'

Comment: No records are updated because the table `1042sTransactions` is not defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try joining the two tables:

```
UPDATE  1042sRegistration INNER JOIN 1042sTransactions ON 
                1042sRegistration.AccountNumber = 1042sTransactions.AccountNumber
SET     1042sRegistration.IssueNumber = 1042sTransactions.IssueNumber
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your intention is:

```
UPDATE 1042sRegistration
    SET [1042sRegistration].IssueNumber = (SELECT [1042sTransactions].IssueNumber
                                           FROM [1042sTransactions]
                                           WHERE [1042sRegistration].AccountNumber = [1042sTransactions].AccountNumber
                                          );
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I've tried your fix but I get a different error:  "Operation must use an updateable query."  I've tried a number of workarounds for this as well as in re-saving to confirm it's not a permissions error, and adding DISTINCTROW.  But still getting that error